# Simulated Annealing for graph coloring

Tags: algorithm, simulated-annealing

I am working on a [simulated annealing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing) algorithm for graph coloring. I am following [this](http://riad.pk.edu.pl/~zk/pubs/PPAM07_2.pdf) model, but I am having troubles understanding the cooling schedule and more specifically, the section with the variable M. In my understanding M represents the number of iterations after which the temperature should be changed.

Also, as I understand it, the algorithm focuses on finding a proper color distribution, given the chromatic number and not on finding its value. Since there is no focus on finding the chromatic number, but rather on a coloring with cost low enough, I decided to try "repurpose" the algorithm by setting an upper boundary of colors via [Brook's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brooks%27_theorem) and using binary search to adjust the target cost, eventually finding a solution with low chromatic number that works. This model, however, may prove slower, so I wanted to ask if you could suggest any better solutions?

Thank you :)

Comment: Might be more suited for [Computer Science Stack Exchange](http://cs.stackexchange.com)

Comment: you can check my solution for this problem.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/52450289/601288